# How can i add StdOut to a top of a file (not the bottom)?

Tags: linux, bash, gnu

I am using bash with linux to accomplish adding content to the top of a file.
Thus far i know that i am able to get this done by using a temporary file. so
i am doing it this way:

```
tac lines.bar > lines.foo
echo "a" >> lines.foo 
tac lines.foo > lines.bar
```

But is there a better way of doing this without having to write a second file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo a | cat - file1 > file2
```

same as shellter's

and sed in one line.

```
sed -i -e '1 i<whatever>' file1
```

this will insert  to file1 inplace.
[the sed example i referred to](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/11/unix-sed-tutorial-append-insert-replace-and-count-file-lines/#append_lines)

Answer (score 0):

tac is very 'expensive' solution, especially as you need to use it 2x. While you still need to use a tmp file, this will take less time:

**edit** per notes from KeithThompson, now using '.$$' filename and condtional `/bin/mv`.

```
  { 
     echo "a" 
     cat file1
  } > file1.$$  && /bin/mv file1.$$ file1
```

I hope this helps

Comment: I'd probably write that as `( echo "a" ; cat file1 ) > file1.$$ && mv file1.$$ file1`.  The `.$$` suffix avoids clobbering any existing files, and the `&&` avoids clobbering `file` if the command fails.

Comment: An excellent upgrade, thanks. I'd still like to believe that `{ }` process groups are more efficient, although in practice I always see sub-processes being spawned for things like this.

Answer (score 0):

Using a *named pipe* and *in place replacement* with `sed`, you could add the output of a command at the top of a file without explicitly needing a temporary file:

```
mkfifo output
your_command >> output &
sed -i -e '1x' -e '1routput' -e '1d' -e '2{H;x}' file
rm output
```

What this does is buffering the output of `your_command` in a named pipe (fifo), and inserts *in place* this output using the `r` command of `sed`.  For that, you need to start `your_command` in the background to avoid blocking on output in the fifo.

Note that the `r` command output the file at the end of the cycle, so we need to buffer the 1st line of file in the hold space, outputting it with the 2nd line.

I write *without explicitly needing a temporary file* as `sed` might use one for itself.